# How to Change Row Location in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

I am using jqgrid with MVC and for now, I want change Row location when click on ^ to get one line up and inverse.

actually I want to set 'up' and 'down' signs to every row for change one level row locations

any body can help me?!

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @TonyTomov 5.4.0-Trial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible solution. One of them is to use custom formtter to define the buttons and then bind event on loadComplete to move the rows using the jquery. Below the code:

```
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mydata,
            height: 250,
            width: 780,
            colModel: [
                { label :'move', formatter : myformatter, width:95},
                { label: 'Inv No', name: 'id', width: 75, key:true },
                { label: 'Date', name: 'invdate', width: 90 },
                { label: 'Client', name: 'name', width: 100 },
                { label: 'Amount', name: 'amount', width: 80 },
                { label: 'Tax', name: 'tax', width: 80 },
                { label: 'Total', name: 'total', width: 80 },
                { label: 'Notes', name: 'note', width: 150 }
            ],
            viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data rang and total records on the toolbar
            caption: "Load jqGrid through Javascript Array",
            loadComplete : function() {
              $(".up,.down").on('click', function () {
                 var row = $(this).closest("tr.jqgrow");
                 if($(this).is('.up')){
                    row.insertBefore(row.prev());
                 } else {
                    row.insertAfter(row.next());
                 }                    
              });
            }
        });
        function myformatter() {
            return '<button class="up" >Up</button>' + '<button class="down">Down</button>';
        }
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/guriddo/7yhLw05b/45/)

Comment: Thanks Tony some another questions! - how can send row id to server side with ajax or some else? - how can add two extra button for get the row to the first and the last record of grid?

Comment: I highly recommend yo to consult the docs - see grid methods. About the first and last record of the grid - there are a lot of conditions which may differ - by example is your datatype local, should we take care of the current sort and etc. If you have question no related to the current one, you may need to open new thread

Comment: I solved these issues with your help.
Thank you very much.